# How do I make the primary key id field of megaprotouser String instead of Long?

Tags: scala, lift, traits

I am trying to make the primary key id field of `MegaProtoUser` `String` instead of `Long`. I was thinking to extend the `MegaProtoUser` trait and override its members, but I would have to override a protected class (I think) which is not allowed in Scala. Because I couldn't figure out how to extend `MegaProtoUser`, I decided to write my own versions of this trait (see below) and mixing it in as follows:

```
class User extends StringMegaProtoUser[User] with CreatedUpdatedNotEditable {
  def getSingleton = User //
  ...
}
```

This doesn't work. The compiler complains about foreign keys that I have defined in the User model not being of the correct type. Can anyone advise on how to extend MegaProtoUser so that it uses a String id instead of a Long id?

Thanks!

UPDATE: In the code below, in response to the comment below I changed `KeyedMapper[Long, T]` to `KeyedMapper[String, T]`. This didn't solve the problem: when I use this new StringMegaProtoUser as above, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
[error] ..../src/main/scala/code/model/User.scala:39: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : code.model.User.type
[error]  required: net.liftweb.mapper.KeyedMetaMapper[String,code.model.User]
[error]   def getSingleton = User // what's the "meta" server
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this? Thanks!

```
trait StringProtoUser[T <: net.liftweb.mapper.StringProtoUser[T]]
extends KeyedMapper[Long, T] with UserIdAsString {
  self: T =>

  override def primaryKeyField: MappedStringIndex[T] = id

  /**
   * The primary key field for the User.  You can override the behavior
   * of this field:
   * <pre name="code" class="scala">
   * override lazy val id = new MyMappedLongClass(this) {
   *   println("I am doing something different")
   * }
   * </pre>
   */
  lazy val id: MappedStringIndex[T] = new MyMappedStringClass(this)

  protected class MyMappedStringClass(obj: T) extends MappedStringIndex(obj, 50)

  /**
   * Convert the id to a String
   */
  def userIdAsString: String = id.get.toString

  /**
   * The first name field for the User.  You can override the behavior
   * of this field:
   * <pre name="code" class="scala">
   * override lazy val firstName = new MyFirstName(this, 32) {
   *   println("I am doing something different")
   * }
   * </pre>
   */

  lazy val firstName: MappedString[T] = new MyFirstName(this, 32)

  protected class MyFirstName(obj: T, size: Int) extends
MappedString(obj, size) {
    override def displayName = fieldOwner.firstNameDisplayName
    override val fieldId = Some(Text("txtFirstName"))
  }

  /**
   * The string name for the first name field
   */
  def firstNameDisplayName = S.?("first.name")

  /**
   * The last field for the User.  You can override the behavior
   * of this field:
   * <pre name="code" class="scala">
   * override lazy val lastName = new MyLastName(this, 32) {
   *   println("I am doing something different")
   * }
   * </pre>
   */
  lazy val lastName: MappedString[T] = new MyLastName(this, 32)

  protected class MyLastName(obj: T, size: Int) extends
MappedString(obj, size) {
    override def displayName = fieldOwner.lastNameDisplayName
    override val fieldId = Some(Text("txtLastName"))
  }

  /**
   * The last name string
   */
  def lastNameDisplayName = S.?("last.name")

  /**
   * The email field for the User.  You can override the behavior
   * of this field:
   * <pre name="code" class="scala">
   * override lazy val email = new MyEmail(this, 48) {
   *   println("I am doing something different")
   * }
   * </pre>
   */
  lazy val email: MappedEmail[T] = new MyEmail(this, 48)

  protected class MyEmail(obj: T, size: Int) extends MappedEmail(obj, size) {
    override def dbIndexed_? = true
    override def validations = valUnique(S.?("unique.email.address"))
_ :: super.validations
    override def displayName = fieldOwner.emailDisplayName
    override val fieldId = Some(Text("txtEmail"))
  }

  /**
   * The email first name
   */
  def emailDisplayName = S.?("email.address")

  /**
   * The password field for the User.  You can override the behavior
   * of this field:
   * <pre name="code" class="scala">
   * override lazy val password = new MyPassword(this) {
   *   println("I am doing something different")
   * }
   * </pre>
   */
  lazy val password: MappedPassword[T] = new MyPassword(this)

  protected class MyPassword(obj: T) extends MappedPassword(obj) {
    override def displayName = fieldOwner.passwordDisplayName
  }

  /**
   * The display name for the password field
   */
  def passwordDisplayName = S.?("password")

  /**
   * The superuser field for the User.  You can override the behavior
   * of this field:
   * <pre name="code" class="scala">
   * override lazy val superUser = new MySuperUser(this) {
   *   println("I am doing something different")
   * }
   * </pre>
   */
  lazy val superUser: MappedBoolean[T] = new MySuperUser(this)

  protected class MySuperUser(obj: T) extends MappedBoolean(obj) {
    override def defaultValue = false
  }

  def niceName: String = (firstName.get, lastName.get, email.get) match {
    case (f, l, e) if f.length > 1 && l.length > 1 => f+" "+l+" ("+e+")"
    case (f, _, e) if f.length > 1 => f+" ("+e+")"
    case (_, l, e) if l.length > 1 => l+" ("+e+")"
    case (_, _, e) => e
  }

  def shortName: String = (firstName.get, lastName.get) match {
    case (f, l) if f.length > 1 && l.length > 1 => f+" "+l
    case (f, _) if f.length > 1 => f
    case (_, l) if l.length > 1 => l
    case _ => email.get
  }

  def niceNameWEmailLink = <a href={"mailto:"+email.get}>{niceName}</a>
}

trait StringMegaProtoUser[T <: StringMegaProtoUser[T]] extends
StringProtoUser[T] {
  self: T =>

  /**
   * The unique id field for the User. This field
   * is used for validation, lost passwords, etc.
   * You can override the behavior
   * of this field:
   * <pre name="code" class="scala">
   * override lazy val uniqueId = new MyUniqueId(this, 32) {
   *   println("I am doing something different")
   * }
   * </pre>
   */
  lazy val uniqueId: MappedUniqueId[T] = new MyUniqueId(this, 32)

  protected class MyUniqueId(obj: T, size: Int) extends
MappedUniqueId(obj, size) {
    override def dbIndexed_? = true
    override def writePermission_?  = true
  }

  /**
   * The has the user been validated.
   * You can override the behavior
   * of this field:
   * <pre name="code" class="scala">
   * override lazy val validated = new MyValidated(this, 32) {
   *   println("I am doing something different")
   * }
   * </pre>
   */
  lazy val validated: MappedBoolean[T] = new MyValidated(this)

  protected class MyValidated(obj: T) extends MappedBoolean[T](obj) {
    override def defaultValue = false
    override val fieldId = Some(Text("txtValidated"))
  }

  /**
   * The locale field for the User.
   * You can override the behavior
   * of this field:
   * <pre name="code" class="scala">
   * override lazy val locale = new MyLocale(this, 32) {
   *   println("I am doing something different")
   * }
   * </pre>
   */
  lazy val locale = new MyLocale(this)

  protected class MyLocale(obj: T) extends MappedLocale[T](obj) {
    override def displayName = fieldOwner.localeDisplayName
    override val fieldId = Some(Text("txtLocale"))
  }

  /**
   * The time zone field for the User.
   * You can override the behavior
   * of this field:
   * <pre name="code" class="scala">
   * override lazy val timezone = new MyTimeZone(this, 32) {
   *   println("I am doing something different")
   * }
   * </pre>
   */
  lazy val timezone = new MyTimeZone(this)

  protected class MyTimeZone(obj: T) extends MappedTimeZone[T](obj) {
    override def displayName = fieldOwner.timezoneDisplayName
    override val fieldId = Some(Text("txtTimeZone"))
  }

  /**
   * The string for the timezone field
   */
  def timezoneDisplayName = S.?("time.zone")

  /**
   * The string for the locale field
   */
  def localeDisplayName = S.?("locale") 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the type parameters to `KeyedMapper[String, T]` - from the scaladoc it looks like the [first parameter is the key type](http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/index.html#net.liftweb.mapper.KeyedMapper)

Comment: Doh! Thanks, I should be better about using CMD+F. I made the change you suggested, but it still doesn't work. When I use `class User extends StringMegaProtoUser[User] { def getSingleton = User // what's the "meta" server ... }` the compiler complains: `type mismatch; found   : code.model.User.type  required: net.liftweb.mapper.KeyedMetaMapper[String,code.model.User] def getSingleton = User` (I'll update the question to show the formatting better). Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!